# Template extending in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, templates, progressive-web-apps

I want to use template extending in **Vanilla Js apps** , so that I can create an app shell and then extend the contents, just like the one we do in Python Django, please suggest any frameworks/library in Js to do basic routing and template extending to keep the project organised.

Answer (score 0):

`Nunjucks` has similar syntax to django templating engine & 'jinja2'. In fact `nunjucks` inspired from jinja2

Note that Nunjucks is not 100% same as jinja2

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/